# VirtualBox Mac OS Host and Windows 10 Guest with USB Phone Tethering on Guest to Share With Host

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Just as the title says, I am using Virtualbox on a Mac OS host and trying to run a Windows 10 guest that has an Android phone connected to it over USB for tethering. I got so far as using USB filtering to have the Android phone connect with the Win 10 guest and have it connecting to the phone. Furthermore, the Android phone is working and tethering over USB the internet to the guest (woohoo!).

Now the next step I'd like to figure out is how to take the USB tethered connection inside the Windows 10 guest and share that with the Mac OS host. I had done some searching and thought that I needed to create a host-only adapter and then use Windows Sharing to share the USB tethered network adapter with the host-only adapter. I tried this to no avail, and I am certain I am missing a step. Any ideas?

**To put it simply: How do you share the internet within the Virtualbox guest with the host?**

(For those interested: What my ultimate goal is to do is to bond a few connections (including that one) on the Mac host using Speedify, and then share that over an Ethernet connection to a Wifi router.)

Comment: Host Only isolates a machine. Use NAT networking and then connect the guest to the host.

Comment: When you say "connect the guest to the host" - what do you mean?  If I use NAT, it would share internet from host to guest.

Comment: You need a NAT (Internal network) connection between guest and host so you can try to share the networking. (1) I have this kind of setup here; (2) I generally do networking at the Host and share to guest. That is much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately the app I am using is only Win 10 available, so I have to do it in the guest to share to the host.  How would I share the USB tethered connection with the host with NAT?

Comment: See if you can connect the the Android hostspot with the host.

Comment: Only Win 10 available for the app for USB tethering, so I can't connect to host directly on Mac.  I just don't see how it would work with NAT to share internet from guest to host.

Comment: I have only ever seen USB connect to either guest or host, not both at the same time. So you cannot use USB in both setups. NAT was a suggestion because I know Host Only won't work. You need to see if you can access the hotspot from your MAC once it is running.  Perhaps forget virtual machines and just use the Android as a self contained hotspot.

Comment: Tried NAT and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919), so I have 2 questions: 1) is your main goal to have an internet connection on Mac OS, possibly using a USB tether? and 2) other than for USB tether, do you still have a need for VirtualBox running Windows 10? Note that we also have a sister site for Apple products, [apple.se], and they have some questions regarding [Android USB tether](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=android+usb+tether).

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I could see how that might seem that way, but all I am looking to do is to share guest internet with the host... that seems pretty specific.

Comment: I was able to find an article that is fairly close: https://askubuntu.com/questions/433617/how-to-share-virtualbox-windows-xp-guests-internet-connection-with-ubuntu-13-10

I tried following the second step.

However, at the Mac OS level it appears I cannot set a gateway for the vboxnet0 host-only adapter.  It won't show up under the network adapters under System Preferences, and I tried doing a "route add -inet" command to no avail.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to share the internet from a Windows 10 guest with the Mac OS host.  A few things:

1. You need to create a host adapter on the Mac OS.  This is not currently possible (that I know of) with Virtualbox.  Virtualbox creates a vboxnetX network adapter but it isn't visible from the "Network" under "System Preferences".  You need this to show up here in order to specify a "Router" (Gateway).  I tried several posts online that used the Terminal to manually set the Router/Gateway without any luck.  **In order to make this work, I had to download/buy Parallels Desktop Pro edition: https://kb.parallels.com/5557**.  Hopefully Virtualbox will support the creation of this network adapter under the "System Preferences" in the future.
2. Once I downloaded/bought Parallels, it still would not work after following the instructions.  The reason for this is that when sharing a connection using ICS in Windows 10, it will reset the host-only network adapter IP Address in the guest to a default of 192.168.137.1.  This IP will override ANY static IP that is set under the adapter settings.  In order to set your own, you need to set the desired IP in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters` for the following Values `ScopeAddress`, `ScopeAddressBackup`, and `StandaloneDHCPAddress`.  For whatever reason, I could not get this to work for setting my desired IP (`192.168.100.128`), but was able to get it to work when I set the registry value to `192.168.100.1` (maybe someone else's experience will differ?) - note the key here being the last of the octet ending in "1".

Notes:

- It was helpful to view under Parallels > Devices > Network (IP address) and running `ipconfig /all` to see what the adapter ACTUALLY is vs. what you set it for.  This took me a while to find out that no matter what I told the adapter to set the IP to, it ignored me and set it to a default value found in the registry.  In order to get this to work, you MUST make sure the IP address on your host-only network adapter in Windows 10 matches the one specified on your Mac OS host-only network adapter's Router/Gateway setting (now found under Network in System Preferences).
- Also, if you're doing a lot of tweaking, make sure that a rogue IP address doesn't bind itself to the Windows 10 host-only adapter.  Check the "Advanced" tab when configuring the "IPv4" portion of the network adapter to make sure there isn't multiple IPs associated with the host-only adapter.

Hope this helps someone else that has ripped their hair out like me trying to get this to work.